# Unable to Compile Nutch

Tags: package-management, java, dependencies, apache-ant

I am trying to build a crawler with Apache Nutch,Hbase and ELK
My idea is to crawl .onion sites.
I am fairly new to this, so please bare with me

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 server
Java version:
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
Nutch Version: 2.4 ( I believe it is the latest)

I am able to start HBase, but when i try to compile nutch by running the following:

```
ant runtime
```

I am getting the following error

```
[ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]           module not found: org.restlet.jse#org.restlet;2.2.3
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.restlet.jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet;2.2.3!org.restlet.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.restlet.jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/jars/org.restlet.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/org.restlet-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet;2.2.3!org.restlet.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/org.restlet-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== sonatype: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/org.restlet-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet;2.2.3!org.restlet.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/org.restlet-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== apache-snapshot: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/org.restlet-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet;2.2.3!org.restlet.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/org.restlet-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== spring-plugins: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/org.restlet-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet;2.2.3!org.restlet.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.2.3/org.restlet-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]           module not found: org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jackson;2.2.3
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.restlet.jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jackson;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.restlet.jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/jars/org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jackson;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== sonatype: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jackson;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== apache-snapshot: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jackson;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== spring-plugins: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jackson;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jackson/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]           module not found: org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jaxrs;2.2.3
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.restlet.jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jaxrs;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.restlet.jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/jars/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jaxrs;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== sonatype: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jaxrs;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== apache-snapshot: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jaxrs;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== spring-plugins: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jaxrs;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.jaxrs-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]           module not found: org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.crypto;2.2.3
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.restlet.jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.crypto;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.crypto.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.restlet.jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/jars/org.restlet.ext.crypto.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.crypto-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.crypto;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.crypto.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.crypto-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== sonatype: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.crypto-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.crypto;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.crypto.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.crypto-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== apache-snapshot: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.crypto-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.crypto;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.crypto.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.crypto-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== spring-plugins: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.crypto-2.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.crypto;2.2.3!org.restlet.ext.crypto.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.crypto/2.2.3/org.restlet.ext.crypto-2.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]           module not found: org.apache.hbase#hbase-commons;1.2.3
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.apache.hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hbase#hbase-commons;1.2.3!hbase-commons.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /root/.ivy2/local/org.apache.hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/jars/hbase-commons.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/hbase-commons-1.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hbase#hbase-commons;1.2.3!hbase-commons.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/hbase-commons-1.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== sonatype: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/hbase-commons-1.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hbase#hbase-commons;1.2.3!hbase-commons.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/hbase-commons-1.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== apache-snapshot: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/hbase-commons-1.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hbase#hbase-commons;1.2.3!hbase-commons.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/hbase-commons-1.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== spring-plugins: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/apache/hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/hbase-commons-1.2.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.hbase#hbase-commons;1.2.3!hbase-commons.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/apache/hbase/hbase-commons/1.2.3/hbase-commons-1.2.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.restlet.jse#org.restlet;2.2.3: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jackson;2.2.3: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.restlet.jse#org.restlet.ext.jaxrs;2.2.3: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.crypto;2.2.3: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.hbase#hbase-commons;1.2.3: not found
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
/home/crawl/nutch/nutch/build.xml:537: impossible to resolve dependencies:
        resolve failed - see output for details
```

i was able to the rest of the repositories.

Any idea what am i doing wrong?
i tried updating my time zone.
Adding Maven's repo to /etc/apt/source.list
I am still getting the same error
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I was not able to find hbase-commons in maven repository. Though I found [hbase-common](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase-common/). Similary I can't find [restlet](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/). Also according to [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/), development of 2.x has been frozen since 2019. However, they are actively updating 1.x. Moreover, are you using `root` account to compile?

Comment: yeah, i am using root to compile. i am trying out 1.x now, let see if it works
Edit: the naming convention is confusing

Comment: Please try to avoid using root account unless it's really needed.

Comment: yeah haha of course, this is just some experiment i am tryna do.
Nevertheless, i managed to get it fixed with Nutch 1.18

Comment: Excellent!!! Consider posting that as an answer.